# How to test @Input up to date checks in Gradle plugins?

Tags: gradle

I'm writing my first Gradle plugin.  It creates a task that has several @Input...-annotated methods.  I think I've defined them correctly, but I don't understand how to correctly test these declarations.  I need to able to write an integration test (I wouldn't call this a unit test) that sets up a minimal environment, declares a set of input to be "up to date", pretends to run a build, and then picks a component in the "input" space to change, and then verifies that the task thinks it needs to be run again.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's wise to spend time on "testing gradle", because I think that's exactly what you're planning to do.. (referring to the up-to-date/changed test - which is core gradle functionality)... Well, that's my belief, feel free to disagree. It sill makes sense to test the functionality of your plugin, yet I would test that "without gradle": separate it in separate class(es) and start testing from there.

Comment: The processing of the result of an "up to date" decision is certainly core gradle processing.  The logic in those methods is not. Ask yourself this: If you write a complex plugin with @Input...-annotated methods, and because of a bug in one of those methods (your code), the task isn't run when one or more of its inputs have changed, then whose fault is it?

Comment: yep, you're right. I was assuming the up-to-date check was completely "out of your hands" but that does not seem to be the case. My mistake.. Well then, also curious on the coming responses..